# Using host.json file to disable some azure functions locally

Tags: azure-functions

I know that it is possible to disable some Azure Functions from enabling localy using file host.json just adding list of needed Functions.
In official docs it said that is "Intended for use only when running locally". But if I this file will be sync with Azure, functions out of the list also will be disabled in Azure?

```
{
"functions": [ "QueueProcessor", "GitHubWebHook" ]}
```

Comment: It still works on azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you set this on local, then when you publish it to azure, the host.json file will also be published and still work. After published, only QueueProcessor and GitHubWebHook will  be loaded.

[image]